# Default JxBrowser print handler limits printing to 100 pages

Tags: printing, default, jxbrowser

I've noticed that when using Jxbrowser's default print dialog (using JxBrowser version 6.7) and printing a document with many pages, the page selection only goes up to 100 pages.

When you type in more than 100, it reverts back to the previously set number and you can't increment to more than 100.

Is this just me?

Comment: What about Google Chrome? Can you print the same web page with 100 pages in Google Chrome?

Comment: What I have been testing with is a pdf document. When opening the document Chrome, the print dialog allows you to select pages over page 100 in the page-range text box.  In JxBrowser, pages are selected with two number inputs, both cap out at 100.

Comment: Oh, that's the issue in default print dialog implementation. The maximum number of pages is hardcoded to 100 in the default print dialog. We fix update default print dialog implementation in next EAP update and let you know the results.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find this mentioned anywhere!

Comment: That's an internal undocumented limitation, that we will remove in next version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am here to inform you that we’ve just released JxBrowser 6.14 where the mentioned issue has been resolved.

This version is available for downloading at https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing you to let you know that the issue has been fixed. You can download EAP build with the fix from https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/eap/jxbrowser-6.14-b13-eap-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip

The fix will be included in official 6.14 release probably this month.